# Woocommerce Deposit, then random payments until product paid in full

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have been searching for a solution to this for days, so I am hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction before I pull whats left of my hair out lol.

Having purchased a number of plugins from places like codecanyon, trying all (I think) of the deposit plugins on the wordpress.org repository and emailing plugin authors to see if their plugins can do such a thing and pulling github apart, I am here as a last resort.

The funcitonalty I am looking for, which I thought would have been a basic feature on deposit plugins, is to let customers pay off their balance as they want to.

Example scenario:

Buyer purchases product for €1000 and pays a deposit of €300 during checkout, leaving €700 left to pay. We don't want to set the buyer to an payment schedule, instead we would like them to log in at any time and pay off what they can afford at that time, until the full payment has been made.

I have looked at other solutions like using a wallet, where the buyer tops up their wallet amount, but this is an extra step a customer should not need to take.

If anyone has any ideas, or has achieved something similar, I would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Cheers,

Eoin